# Dynamically add and remove form elements within the group

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form and I am trying to generate multiple input form element and remove with the remove button. As the generated form element has other set of form elements where it can be added and removed separately. When I click the 'Add Wall' on the new generated elements the adding getting on first section only. It should be added and removed in same section where the 'Add Wall' is
 Here is the code I have tried

https://jsfiddle.net/m20w0p1p/

```
<!-- BEGIN FORM-->
<div class="form-body">

  <div class="control-group" id="fields">

    <div class="controls">
      <form role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post" id="voilation">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                                </span>
            <input type="text" name="title"> </div>
        </div>


        <div class="entry input-group col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Floor</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                <input class="form-control" name="floor[]" type="text" placeholder="Floor" /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Wall/Celing</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                <input class="form-control" name="celing[]" value="celing" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Length</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                <input class="form-control" name="length[]" type="text" placeholder="Length" /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Height</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                <input class="form-control" name="breadth[]" type="text" placeholder="Breadth" /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Thickness</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                <input class="form-control" name="material[]" type="text" placeholder="Material" />

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label></label>
              <div class="input-group">

                <input class="form-control" name="thickness[]" type="hidden" placeholder="Thickness" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                                                                <span class="">Add</span>
                </button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label></label>
              <div class="input-group">

                <input class="form-control" name="wall[]" type="hidden" placeholder="WAll" /> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="subcontrol">
            <div class="section">
              <div class="subentry input-group col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label></label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                      <input class="form-control" name="wall[]" value="Wall" type="text" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Length</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                      <input class="form-control" name="wall_length[]" placeholder="Length" type="text" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Height</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                                                                        </span>
                      <input class="form-control" name="height[]" type="text" placeholder="Height" />
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add-wall" type="button">
                                                                                <span class="">Add Wall</span>
                      </button>
                      </span>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>



        <div class="form-actions left">
          <button type="submit" class="btn green"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <!-- END FORM-->

$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function (e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();

                var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
                        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
                        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
                newEntry.find('input').val('');
                controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
                        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">Remove Floor</span>');
            }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function (e)
            {
                $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
            //Add wall
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-add-wall', function (e)
            {

                e.preventDefault();

                var controlForm = $('.subcontrol').first(),
                        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.subentry:last'),
                        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
                newEntry.find('input').val('');
                controlForm.find('.subentry:not(:last) .btn-add-wall')
                        .removeClass('btn-add-wall').addClass('btn-remove-wall')
                        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">Remove Wall</span>');
            }).on('click', '.btn-remove-wall', function (e)
            {
                $(this).parents('.subentry:first').remove();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I thought it would be helpful. What should I change do I need to minimize the code into simpler form.